# Get friends from specific location

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

How to get Friends from particular location using facebook fql and graph

i tried fql as

```
  SELECT uid FROM user WHERE  current_location   IN ('Chennai','Tamilnadu')   AND uid IN 
   (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me() )
```

It shows

```
  {
"data": [

  ]
}
```

and i got all neccessary permission too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First**, `current_location` is a structure so `current_location IN ('Chennai','Tamilnadu')` won't work.
You need to specify any field from the structure, i.e.:

```
current_location.city
current_location.state
```

**Second**, only your friends who have authorized your app will be found. For example, a friend of mine from London is using the Graph API Explorer. This is new since the introduction of v2.0 Facebook API. [Read more here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog).

So, this query:

```
SELECT uid, current_location 
  FROM user 
 WHERE current_location.city IN ('London')   
   AND uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me() )
```

Gives:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "uid": "73221xxx", 
      "current_location": {
        "city": "London", 
        "state": "England", 
        "country": "United Kingdom", 
        "zip": "", 
        "latitude": 51.5072, 
        "longitude": -0.1275, 
        "id": "106078429431815", 
        "name": "London, United Kingdom"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```